# lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit - on 2 pcs

Tags: server

After installing Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS i have the following problem on two pcs.

> lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit.
>   lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit.
>   /dev/mapper/serverjonas--vg-root: clean, ...

There are a few topics about that problem, but I can't find any solution. ( or i don't understand them).

Do you have any idea how this happens?

Thanks and merry christmas

Answer (score 1):

This is normal if you used full disk encryption. When operating systems derived from Debian are installed with full disk encryption what happens is that the installer makes a small unecrypted partition for `/boot` and a large partition holding a LUKS container; in the LUKS container is placed an LVM volume group, holding a logical volume for the root filesystem, and possibly other logical volumes.

When the system boots the LUKS container is opened and the LVM logical volumes need to be activated; normally this is done with the help of `lvmetad`, the LVM metadata daemon, but since the system has just booted and nothing runs yet there is no `lvmetad` and the logical volumes need to be activated by explicitly scanning the container and looking for them.

A similar situation occurs even without encryption if the root filesystem is placed on a LVM logical volume.

In short: it's not an error, it's the normal situation, and the system is just telling you what it's doing.